# unable in retrieving appropriate values from database Using order by and limit

Tags: java, mysql

I have the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY variable1 
LIMIT 5;
```

But it is giving me the  least to higher values  from the database I want to extract those values which are maximum of all and then in decreasing order  in that variable1 column.

There is a coloumn of percent in my table so i need those values from percent which are at maximum like

```
100 ,100,60,50,70,80 etc
```

now i want that they should be displayed in a manner like

```
100 ,100, 80,70 ,60
```

but it is not displaying like this i have used the query

```
select * from tablename order by percent limit 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `desc`

```
select * from tablename 
order by percent desc
limit 10
```

If you don't provide a order, the default is `asc` - ascending. If you want the opposite use `desc` - descending.

If the query still does not work for you then your `percent` column has not a number data type.

Comment: Yeah but it is not working properly because in my table there are 3-4 values which are 100% and it is not displaying them

Comment: Please add example data and expected output directly into your question

Comment: There is a coloumn of percent in my table  so i need those values from percent which are at maximum  like 100 ,100,60,50,70 etc now i want that they should be displayed in a manner like 100 ,100, 70 ,60,50 but it is not displaying like this i have used the query       select * from tablename order by percent limit 10;

Comment: Please put that into your question. Edit it.

Comment: Updated the answer.